# Получить статистику курса валют за определенный промежуток времени

Tags: android, api

Пишу приложение связанное с курсом валют. Курс получаю с помощью api [Yahoo Finance](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDMXN%22%29). Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как то получить с помощью данного сервиса статистику изменения курса например(USD/RUB за месяц), для построения графика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится получение статистики курса валют пример [Курс валют USD-UAH за год](https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/USDUAH=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/json/), в строке запроса можно указать любой промежуток например 1d, 5d, 6m, 5y, ну и конечно любые валюты

Answer (score 2):

На YQL храняться исторические данные акций и курсов валют. Чтобы получить их вбейте в консоль YQL следующее:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
WHERE 
    symbol = "EUR=X" 
AND 
    startDate = "2009-09-11" 
AND 
    endDate = "2010-03-10"
```

Здесь есть одно но - валюту можно получить только относительно к доллару.